# Pasar % como argumento por una Url Spring-boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Hola coders espero que esten bien
les quiero hacer una consulta tengo que hacer este endpoint **"api/compliance/password/{password}"** y el password debe cumplir con ciertos requisitos Complexity =
at least 8 characters
at least one digit
**at least one special character (!,#,$,%,&,@)**
at least one uppercase letter

les dejo el metodo que he creado para hacer esas validaciones

```
public Compliance validatePassword(String password) {
        boolean isPasswordValid = true;
        final String MUST_CONTAIN_ONE_UPPERCASE_LETTER = "^.*[A-Z]+.*$";
        final String MUST_CONTAIN_ONE_DIGIT = "^.*[0-9]+.*$";
        final String MUST_CONTAIN_ONE_SPECIAL_CHARACTER = "^.*[!&$%@]+.*$";

        List<String> reasonsForInvalidPassword = new ArrayList<>();

        if (password.length() < 8) {
            reasonsForInvalidPassword.add("Password must be at least 8 character long");
            isPasswordValid = false;
        }

        if (!password.matches(MUST_CONTAIN_ONE_UPPERCASE_LETTER)) {
            reasonsForInvalidPassword.add("Password must be at least one upper case letter");
            isPasswordValid = false;
        }

        if (!password.matches(MUST_CONTAIN_ONE_DIGIT)) {
            reasonsForInvalidPassword.add("Password must be at least one digit");
            isPasswordValid = false;
        }

        if (!password.matches(MUST_CONTAIN_ONE_SPECIAL_CHARACTER)) {
            reasonsForInvalidPassword.add("Password must be at least one special character");
            isPasswordValid = false;
        }

        String reason = reasonsForInvalidPassword.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", "));

        return new Compliance(isPasswordValid, reason);
    }
```

tambie les dejo mi metodo getmapping

```
    @GetMapping(path = "/compliance/password/{password}")
    public ResponseEntity<Compliance> getPassword(@PathVariable("password") String password) {
        Compliance compliance = iComplianceService.validatePassword(password);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK)
                .body(compliance);
    }
```

el problema es que acepta todos caracteres especiales exepto **%** me sale un lindo error en postman

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request</title><style type="text/css">body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;} h1, h2, h3, b {color:white;background-color:#525D76;} h1 {font-size:22px;} h2 {font-size:16px;} h3 {font-size:14px;} p {font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style></head><body><h1>HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request</h1><hr class="line" /><p><b>Type</b> Status Report</p><p><b>Message</b> Invalid URI: End of file (EOF)</p><p><b>Description</b> The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).</p><hr class="line" /><h3>Apache Tomcat/9.0.45</h3></body></html>
```

les agradezco por su ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que Postman `no codifica` la URL antes de enviar la petición HTTP y recuerda que el carácter `%` es reservado porque se utiliza para codificar caracteres especiales, lo que debes hacer es `codificar`  la URL antes del envió al servicio.

Por ejemplo si quieres enviar el texto `Prueba%` codificado seria `Prueba%25` porque `%25` representa al carácter `%`, en postman puedes seleccionar el texto en la URL y con clic derecho veras un menu y seleccionas la opción `EncodeURLComponent` y se encargara de escapar los caracteres.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al final en el servicio de spring boot recibirías el texto `Prueba%`.

Comment: lo hice mu tu hiciste en postman y funciono voy a prodecer a codificar la url y te esere avisando gracias